# Rails Installing on Ubuntu cannot load mkmf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install Rails on Ubuntu:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

but I'm having trouble:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
  from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

What is the problem?

Comment: how did you install ruby? Was is the ubuntu default version using apt-get? If so, you may need to install the `-dev` package as well, and ensure that you have installed `build-essential`

Answer (score 12):

As Daniel said in the comments, try and execute `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

Comment: Or, if you're using ruby1.9.1 like me, you'll want to use `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, I have installed successfully on Ubuntu 12.4(You can choose versions during installation, According to your requirements....)

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install build-essential git-core curl libmysqlclient18 nodejs
3. sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
   umask g+w
4. source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
5. sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion
6. sudo chown -R [user]:[user] /usr/local/rvm
   Example : sudo chown -R rohitporwal:rohitporwal /usr/local/rvm
7. source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
8. rvm install 1.9.2
9. sudo gem install rails